# Splitting large text file into smaller text files by Column Values using Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have a very large text file that reads:

```
12/03/2015,1300 ,       .01,15 ,  10024101,QA                                   
12/03/2015,1715 ,       .01,15 ,  10024101,QA                                   
12/03/2015,1730 ,       .04,15 ,  10024102,QA                                   
12/04/2015,0200 ,       .01,15 ,  10024102,QA                                   
12/04/2015,0215 ,       .05,15 ,  10024102,QA                                   
12/04/2015,0245 ,       .01,15 ,  10024103,QA                                   
12/04/2015,0300 ,       .03,15 ,  10024103,QA                                   
12/04/2015,0315 ,       .02,15 ,  10024104,QA                                   
12/04/2015,0330 ,       .03,15 ,  10024105,QA                                   
12/04/2015,0445 ,       .01,15 ,  10024105,QA
```

This file goes on for 300K+ lines. Is there a python script to separate and create a new text file for every unique value in column 5 (ex. a separate text file that has all rows containing 10024101)? The new file would have all rows that pertain to each unique value.

I'd like to do this in python is possible. Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far? Please post your code.

Comment: `pandas` is sort of the canonical solution for anything tabular data like in this case. You would load your csv into a `DataFrame` using `read_csv`, then group rows by value in the 5th column using `groupby`. You can then iterate over the results of `groupby` to get separate `DataFrame`'s which you can then do further processing on or save out as new csv files using `to_csv`.